# zip entry showing directory as files

Tags: java, file, io

hi im trying to extract a zip files 
and the zip file contains the follwoing contents

zipfile.zip:

- zipfile/text1.txt
- zipfile/text2.txt
- zipfile/db/schema/text.txt
- zipfile/artifacts/tex.txt

and this is-my code

```
File file = new File("/home/solomon/originar.zip");
        try {
            InputStream ios = new FileInputStream(file);
            ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(ios);
            File outputfolder = new File(file.getParent()+File.separator+"EXTRACT");
            if(!outputfolder.exists()){
                outputfolder.mkdirs();
            }
            ZipEntry ZENTRY;
            FileOutputStream fos=null;
            while((ZENTRY=zis.getNextEntry())!=null){
                File file1 = new File(outputfolder.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+ZENTRY.getName());
                new File(file1.getParent()).mkdirs();
                System.out.println("filename"+file1.isDirectory());
                if(!file1.isDirectory()){
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(file1);
                    int len;
                    while((len=zis.read())>-1){
                        fos.write(len);
                    }
                }




            }
            fos.close(); 
            zis.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```

`file1.txt` and `file2.txt` has been extracted successfully but when I read `text.txt` which is inside `db/schema` folder this fails because `db` is showing as file instead of folder. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the inline comments

```
// remove the EXTRACT string from the output folder path.I think there is no extract directory 

File outputfolder = new File(file.getParent()+File.separator+"EXTRACT");
.
.
.
   while((ZENTRY=zis.getNextEntry())!=null){
  // remove the outputfolder.getAbsolutePath()
  File file1 = new File(outputfolder+File.separator+ZENTRY.getName());
            new File(file1.getParent()).mkdirs();
            System.out.println("filename::"+ file1.getName()+"::"+file1.isDirectory());
            if(!file1.isDirectory()){
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file1);
                int len;
                while((len=zis.read())>-1){

                    fos.write(len);
                }
                System.out.println("file name on read::"+ file1);
            }
```